# Integrating Wordpress MU Blog into Web Site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress multisite network and it has 6 blogs who's posts I want to extract and put into 6 different pages on a separate website (this separate website is not wordpress based but it is php based). Its kind of like integrating wordpress blog into my own website but it does'nt seem to work for wordpress MU blogs. I spent all morning searching the web on how to do this but have come up with nothing. Anyone have any idea on how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do it is with the free FishPig extension for Magento.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration.html

I use it on all of my sites and it's pretty easy.

You can get then get WordPress MU Integration from this extension:

http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-mu-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are extracting posts from each site, then using feed would be an obvious option to go. just post fix the `/feed` to each blog main url to get posts. In your own site, you will get posts in XML format, you then can parse it with php [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: Thats a good idea. Thanks, I tried it and it only gives me the latest 10 posts. Is there a way to get all posts? Because I would like to create pagination to go through the posts as if it was the blog itself.

Comment: Also I want to get a list of all categories. Is this possible using xml feeds?

Comment: I think you can change the number of output feeds in 'setting->reading->Syndication feeds show the most recent'.

 Getting a list of all categories may not be possible in feeds, but you can create a custom page which output all categories in XML format, it will be the same effect as using feed.